# I have a bootstrap template that lets me display items in categories, but I can't change the default category that appears first on homepage

Tags: javascript, html, filter, element

When I am on the homepage, everything marked as "all" displays first. Instead, I want everything marked as "highlights" to display by default (but then if a different category is clicked, I want that to display, which currently works fine). I have very limited coding experience and have never used this site before, but usually I can figure problems out by just trial and error. This has stumped me!

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-title text-center">
        <h2>MY WORK</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="portfolio-list">

           <ul class="nav list-unstyled" id="portfolio-flters">
              <li class="filter filter-active" data-filter=".highlights">Highlights</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".crime">Crime</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".events">Events</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".sga">SGA</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".podcast">Podcasts</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".wkyt">WKYT</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".wuog">WUOG 90.5 FM</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".video">Video</li>
              <li class="filter" data-filter=".all">All</li>
              </ul></div>
```

And my js:

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({    
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-thumbnail',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });

  $('#portfolio-flters li').on( 'click', function() {
    $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
    $(this).addClass('filter-active');

    portfolioIsotope.isotope({ filter: $(this).data('filter') });
  });

})
```

Comment: After assigning the click handlers to your filters, use `$('#portfolio-flters li').eq(0).click()` to "click" the first one.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!